# Return a string Value from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

I have the following method and stored procedure.

My question is how to return a string value from stored procedure to use in `addStaffName` method ?

```
public string addStaffName()
{
        string staffName = string.Empty;
        string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();
        SqlConnection SqlCOn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        SqlCOn.Open();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCOn;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "FetchStaffName";
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email);
        //???
        return staffName;
    }

create procedure fetchStaffName
    @email varchar(100)
AS 
begin 
    select (employeeName) 
    from employee 
    where email = @email
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can be sure that you'llonly ever get **one row, one column** as a result set - then you can use `.ExecuteScalar()` on your `SqlCommand` like this:

```
string staffName = string.Empty;

string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("FetchStaffName", sqlCon)
{
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

    sqlCon.Open();

    staffName = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    sqlCon.Close();

    return staffName;
}
```

I also put the usage of `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using() { ... }` blocks which is the recommended best practice for anything that's deriving from `IDisposable` to ensure proper disposal of the objects after their use

Comment: thank u so much , nice advice , i can not vote u up , cause i new here !

Comment: but what if i wanted to get two columns as result from stored procedure ?

Comment: @AlirezaX: then you need to use `.ExecuteReader()` and you get back a `SqlDataReader`. With that you can read any number of columns, and any number of rows, and stick the results into objects of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Consider to make `fetchStaffName` a scalar function rather than stored procedure. By definition stored procedures are required to perform a set of actions with data. Scalar function guarantees there will be exactly one output value for the set of input values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fetchStaffName (
 @email VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(?) --Place the length of employeeName field instead of ? symbol.
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT employeeName FROM employee WHERE email = @email)
END
```

And then your .NET code transforms into the following:

```
using (SqlConnection SqlCOn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT fetchStaffName(@email)", SqlCOn);
    SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

    SqlCOn.Open();
    staffName = (string)SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

As you can see `CommandType` changed from `StoredProcedure` to `Text`. I also wrapped the work with SqlConnection object into `using` construction to dispose its resources and close automatically.

Comment: There are several ways of doing so. You can use stored procedure with multiple output parameters (a little bit different .NET and T-SQL syntax). Also you can select a row with several columns inside stored procedure and then use ExecuteReader() method of your SqlCommand. For details create a new question.